# Deviance in a distribution that has a shape parameter

Tags: generalized-linear-model, likelihood, deviance

Consider the following log-likelihood function

$$
\ell (\vec{\mu}, \rho \mid \vec{y}) =
\sum_{i=1}^I \log f(\mu_{i1}, \dotsc, \mu_{iJ}, \rho \mid y_{i1}, \dotsc, y_{iJ})
$$

where $\vec{y}$ ($I \times J$) is the response, $\vec{\mu}$ ($I \times J$) are the corresponding expected values and $\rho$ is some shape parameter.

How do we define the full model?  In the context of GLMs, the full model is defined as a model with $N = I \times J$ parameters, one for each observation.  But here if we set $\hat\mu_{ij} = y_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ there is still one parameter left $\rho$ which has to be assigned some value.

Comment: I think it depends on the exact distribution and how it's affected by the shape parameter. If you meant to say a *scale* parameter, then things get much easier --- It's the ratio of the predicted deviance to the actual deviance.

Comment: Good question. Such models are usually shoe-horned into the generalized linear model framework by stipulating a relation between variance and mean (the latter being a function of the parameters), & estimating a dispersion parameter (not necessarily by maximum-likelihood). The gamma & negative binomial "GLM"s are examples.

Comment: @JDL it's not a scale parameter, it's a parameter related to the joint probability distribution of the $Y_{i1}, \dotsc, Y_{iJ}$. If $\rho = 1$ it means the responses are independently distributed.

Comment: So it's like a correlation parameter? (Except that normally zero correlation implies independence)

Comment: @Scortchi Thanks for the tip. I'll try to find some examples with the negative binomial.

Comment: @JDL yes, it's a correlation parameter and $0$ (not $1$) implies independence (I was wrong)